# Realization of a filter based on its transfer function

Tags: filters, fourier-transform, transfer-function, stability, causality

How can we check whether the filter is realizable given its transfer function and What are the parameters the realization depends on?

Here is an example:

> Show that a filter with transfer function
>
> $H(ω)=\frac{2(10^5)}{ω^2 + 10^{10}} e^{-jωt_0 }$
>
> is unrealizable. Can this filter be made approximately realizable by
> choosing a sufficiently large t<sub>0</sub>.

*--Modern digital and analog communication systems (3rd edition) - B.P. Lathi*

**Note: The question is of general nature. The example quoted above serves only as to make it clear, what is being asked. No one has to provide a solution for this problem.**

Comment: how do you define *"realizable"*?  is a *realizable* filter one that you can build?  does your *realizable* filter have to be stable?  what might be another property you need for your filter to be *"realizable"*?

Comment: By realizable, I mean theoretically functional. We can ignore practical complications.

Comment: then ya gotta define whatever the heck ya mean by *"theoretically functional"*.

Comment: hay, can any of you IEEE folks get this paper: [A Note on Stable, Physically Realizable, Linear, Time Invariant Systems](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1086976/)?  i don't wanna pay money for it.

Comment: maybe [this segment from Rao: Signals & Systems](https://books.google.com/books?id=LDadfi_t5xgC&pg=PA415&lpg=PA415&dq=realizable+LTI+system&source=bl&ots=9IBHWe7v17&sig=D6WHxrZSXBB1sqgc2dvlHwrig4k&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi7_7KTnsPdAhUow4MKHWl9AAUQ6AEwE3oECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=realizable%20LTI%20system&f=false) is what you mean?

Comment: i think the property you mean is **causal**.  Systems that are not causal are somehow able to react to input in the *future*.  And, without getting into weird physics of black holes or of quantum mechanics, i dunno anyone who thinks a system you can physically realize in reality can react to future input values.

Comment: so, Good, can you do partial fraction expansion?  and are you sure that $e^{-j \omega t_0}$ belongs in the denominator?  or maybe it's $e^{+j \omega t_0}$ in the denominator.  or maybe the question should be *"Can this filter be made approximately realizable by choosing a sufficiently large **negative** $t_0$?"*

Comment: okay, now it looks like we gotta valid homework problem.

Comment: My bad $e^{−jωt_0}$ belongs to the numerator

Comment: BTW, HTML markup doesn't go into $\LaTeX$.

Comment: I only added the problem because question was unclear to you. You don't have to provide the solution, neither did I ask anyone to provide the solution. The question is only an example of what I am trying to ask.

Comment: then i would explore the meaning of **causality** in systems.  specifically what does it mean for an system, linear or not, to be *"causal"*?  why is that necessary to be *"realizable"*?  then, more specifically, what does it mean for an LTI system to be *causal*?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83299/discussion-between-goodfellow-and-robert-bristow-johnson).

Comment: i am not a big fan of SE chat.  i would rather continue it here.

Comment: //" why is that [causality] necessary to be 'realizable'? "//  $$ $$ ***really***???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A transfer function is called *realizable* if it can be implemented by a causal and stable system. The given frequency response is continuous and doesn't have any impulses, so the corresponding system is stable.

The transfer function (as a function of $s$) is given by

$$H(s)=\frac{a}{b-s^2}e^{-st_0}\tag{1}$$

The given frequency response is obtained form $(1)$ by substituting $s=j\omega$. Since $b>0$, $H(s)$ has two real-valued poles at $\pm\sqrt{b}$, and, consequently, the corresponding impulse response is two-sided (i.e., non-causal).

Partial fraction expansion of $(1)$ gives

$$H(s)=\frac{a}{2\sqrt{b}}\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}-s}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}+s}\right]e^{-st_0},\qquad -\sqrt{b}<\textrm{Re}\{s\}<\sqrt{b}\tag{2}$$

From $(2)$ it is straightforward to obtain the impulse response

$$\begin{align}h(t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{H(s)\}&=\frac{a}{2\sqrt{b}}\left[e^{\sqrt{b}(t-t_0)}u(-(t-t_0))+e^{-\sqrt{b}(t-t_0)}u(t-t_0)\right]\\&=\frac{a}{2\sqrt{b}}e^{-\sqrt{b}|t-t_0|}\tag{3}\end{align}$$

No matter how large you choose $t_0$, the impulse response will never be causal. However, since the system is stable, the impulse response decays for $|t|\to\infty$, so you can approximate the actual impulse response well by sufficiently shifting it to the right (i.e., by choosing some large $t_0$), and truncating the non-causal part.

Also take a look at [this related question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/35702/4298) and its answer.

Answer (score 1):

The filter realization can be checked by paley-wiener criterion, it should not have any discontinuities in frequency response and it should be absolutely square integrable .if you see the text book you might find it.

Comment: Note that the Paley-Wiener criterion only takes the magnitude into account, not the phase. So if the criterion is satisfied for a given magnitude response, we generally still can't say anything about the causality of the corresponding complex frequency response. The only conclusion we can draw in that case is that it is possible to find a phase such that a system with the given magnitude response is causal.

Comment: Can you state any examples?

Comment: Just take the magnitude of the frequency response of any causal and stable filter, and add a phase term $e^{j\omega \tau}$, $\tau>0$. The resulting frequency response satisfies the Paley-Wiener criterion, but it is not causal.

Comment: i would modify that, @MattL. to say "*add a phase term* $e^{j\omega\tau}$, $\tau > \tau_\text{delay}$",  in case your causal and stable filter has a delay in it such that the impulse response $h(t)=0$ for all $t<\tau_\text{delay}$.